# iOS >> ShareKit >> Lots of Warnings / Latest Version?

Tags: ios, warnings, version, sharekit

I'm implementing ShareKit in my app; I'm using XCode4 and have downloaded the ShareKit version from the [official site](http://getsharekit.com/install/) (I think it's the official one).

Everything is working fine, but I get many warnings from the ShareKit inner files; Things like:

- 'setFont:' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIButton.h:106)
- Class 'FBXMLHandler' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol

etc...

Can it be that there is a newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharekit hasn't been updated by the authors in over a year.  That being said, some things have changed since then (APIs updated, method deprecated, etc.)  However, Sharekit should still work.  If the warnings bother you (as they should), they shouldn't be very difficult to fix.  If you need help, google the specific warnings